# How dereference works in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dereference

I was trying to understand dereferencing in Objective-C and wrote below two methods.

```
-(void)alterStringModelOne:(NSMutableString**)string{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"New string by string = &str"];

    string = &str; //Didn't work
}
-(void)alterStringModelTwo:(NSMutableString**)string{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"New string by *string = str"];

    *string = str; //It works
}
```

In above, ModelOne didn't work while ModelTwo does. How are these two statements different?

**Edit: Tracing their address and type**

myStr = **b260**  of type * CFString

---> Enters method model one

string = d9c4  of type ** NSMutableString //Parameter

str = f750 of * CFString //after str creation

string = d97c of type ** NSMutableString //After assignment: string = &str;

--> method returns

myStr = **b260** * CFString

--> Enters method model two

string = d9c4  of type ** NSMutableString //Parameter

str = **0bc0** of * CFString //after str creation

string = 0bc0 of type * CFString //After assignment: *string = str;

--> Leaves method

myStr = **0bc0** of type * CFString

Comment: The first one wouldn't have worked in plain old C either.  `str` is a local variable whose storage goes "poof" when you return from the method.  Taking it's address is taking the address of garbage.

Comment: If you have a method that returns (void) but has a pass by reference argument **you are doing it wrong**.

Comment: @bbum Thanks. But, like i said, i am playing with dereference to understand it. This code is not meant for any application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: This is not specific to Objective-C. The same behavior exists in C and C++.

```
string = &str;
```

This modifies the value of the local variable `string`.

```
*string = str;
```

This modifies the value pointed to by `string`.

Since `string` is a local variable, changing it (as seen in the first example) does not have any lasting effect. The value it points to is not local, though, so changing that (second example) *does* do what you want.

Comment: Thank you duskwuff. Able to see now. Would it possible for you take it one more level deeper? I just edited capturing last four characters of the address of each variable through this process. Can you help me understand what does it mean when an address is of type ** type. Or a link for me to read? I accept the answer as i get now why one worked and another didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It works just like in C. Objective-C objects are accessed by pointers, so in:

```
NSMutableString *string;
```

`string` is declared as a pointer to the object structure and you work normally with it as if it was the object directly. Then you passed the address of that pointer, which we consider as the object itself. Something like:

```
(NSMutableString **)string
```

is actually

```
((object)*)string
```

If you want to assign something to the original object, you have to use the value that this `string` pointer points to, not itself (as it happens in your model one), otherwise you end up modifying what it points to and not what its address represented. That's why your second model works. You're placing `str`, which is a pointer to an object (which we again consider to be simply an object) over the original pointer, which is the so called object pointed by the `string` pointer.

Be careful with your memory management when doing this.